# Use Approver Field of Object Owner Not Available

Tags: approval-process, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

While configuring Knowledge Approval Process, I don't see the option "Use Approver Field of Knowledge Owner". Any idea why?

Comment: You don't see it at all or is it not selectable?

Comment: Not seeing it at all